# Azure AD B2C - Build link to Self-Service Password reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In previous versions of B2C, we always had two seperate policies (one for sign in, and one for password reset). This is no longer the recommended approach. I am now using the self-service password reset functionality that is built in to the newer sign-in flow.

However the welcome mail that we send to a user after creating their account, used to contain a link directly to the place where they could initially set their password.

It seems that it is impossible to construct a link to the forgot password link...

(the url looks like:https://TENANT.b2clogin.com/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignIn/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?claimsexchange=ForgotPassword&csrf_token=&tx=StateProperties=<....>&p=B2C_1_SignIn)

Which does not seem to be something we can construct and send in an e-mail. (The tokens in the link are different every time)

Is there a way to build this link? What's the work around?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a stand a lone reset endpoint, you'll have to create a new journey for the endpoint, which can call the existing reset subjourney - remember to add a `SendClaims` orchestration step to the end of the journey, after you invoke the `ResetPassword` subjourney.

You can then create a new relaying party for the reset endpoint - this is another XML file much like the `B2C_1A_TrustFrameWorkSignIn.xml` - It this case, you could create one called `B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkPasswordReset.xml`, and specify the claims you want in the reset token - be careful to point the `DefaultUserJourney` to your new reset journey.

Afterwards, the name of the new relaying party file can be used for your reset link.

Comment: This definitely is one step in the right direction from having two flows to do the same thing. I'll need to look into this further to see if it actually simplifies my scenario.

Comment: @MichielCornille Did you look further into this scenario and got to a simpler solution?